# Как сделать непрозрачный iconCaption на Яндекс Карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Все названия меток по умолчанию полупрозрачные. Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать прозрачность, и желательно ещё добавить обводку для iconCaption

Объекты добавляются на карту с помощью JSON

Отрывок, где описывается iconCaption:

```
 "properties": {
                    "clusterCaption": "Aphaenogaster",
                    "iconCaption": "Aphaenogaster Barbara",
                    "rod": "Aphaenogaster",
                    "vid": "Barbara"
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

Изменить внешний вид подписи нельзя. Но можно создать свой макет метки.
Подходящий пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape

```
var circleLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="circle_layout">#</div></div>');

var circlePlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [55.783202, 37.605584], {
        hintContent: 'Метка с круглым HTML макетом'
    }, {
        iconLayout: circleLayout,
        // Описываем фигуру активной области "Круг".
        iconShape: {
            type: 'Circle',
            // Круг описывается в виде центра и радиуса
            coordinates: [0, 0],
            radius: 25
        }
    }
);
map.geoObjects.add(circlePlacemark);
```

Накидал пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/7h8jbd23/1/